# How do I know installed fix packs onTSAMP?

Tags: db2, tivoli

I am investigating vulnerability in these information below.

```
https://www.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21998459  
http://www.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg22005058  
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg22002336
```

However I am not sure those fix packs is already installed or not.
How do I know installed fix packs on TSAMP?

My products version

```
DB2 10.5.8   
TSAMP 4.1.0.3
```

Comment: Do you mean fix packs or interim fixes? Because "TSAMP 4.1.0.3" shows that you have fix pack 3.

Comment: I did not notice your question. YES!!

Answer (score 1):

Check [this IBM link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21426022)
to find information about the samversion command

There is also a command `db2cktsa` documented at [this IBM link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_9.8.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0056997.html)

Comment: I would like to check what kind of fix and interim fix has already applied.